# CkEditor - How to display Font name bigger in the drop-down menu?

Tags: ckeditor

How to display Font name bigger in the drop-down menu ?
They are to small to see the "fancy fonts" style for my eyes. ;-)

**N.B.:** To be clear here I talk about the "Font Name" in the drop menu NOT in the "textarea".

[image]

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dekel ,  It worked fine I've put it in the UserCSS file :) 

One more question if you can help me: When I open CKeditor fresh and I want to paste something in the text area it's always on default font.

Even if Ihad put config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px'; Here's a screenshot to have a better understanding: http://i.imgur.com/aF52FdL.png

I'd like to be able to have Arial 12 as default font when I paste something in the empty textarea.

Comment: You should probably also set this style to the `p` elements in the editable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `editor.css` file you can use:

```
.cke_panel_listItem {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```